# How to make sure all the entries of the mysql database is imported in SAS?

Tags: mysql, database, sas, odbc

I am stuck in SAS while connecting my mysql database through odbc. I have used this command :

```
libname gcdb odbc datasrc="gc" user="" pw="" database="advance_options_report" ;
```

The database is in my localhost.

Although, I have successfully created the library named gcdb, all the tables in it either have one entry or no entry however in mysql database I have multiple entries. Can you please help me and tell me a way how to go about it? I will be really obliged.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show more of what you tried to do. All you have shown is how to define a SAS libref that points to a MYSQL database. You have not shown any attempt to read or write to that database from SAS. Or anything about any particular tables that exist or you want to create in that database.

Comment: if you use MS Excel to access the database through the same ODBC definition, do you see multiple records?  If you have the same problem, then this is an ODBC issue.  If not, probably a SAS issue.

Comment: @Tom First of all thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: @Tom First of all thank you so much for your reply. After running this command I tried proc print data = gcdb.aca_prefix. Although the entries in mysql database for this is 1127 but I got only one on my result window. In the warning section however came this - "Too long column so truncated to 121" I supposed that was because of trailing blanks in the data.

Comment: The truncation of long character variables by PROC PRINT is normal. It was designed for old days of line printers with fixed fonts and 132 characters per line.  The option WIDTH=MIN can reduce that, but will not eliminated it if you really have long text strings in your data. But that should not have caused it to read only one observation.  Try running a data step instead. Then you can see more information.